# How to check notification data in url?

Tags: ios, notifications

I am new to iOS development. I want my app to periodically check a URL for data, and show a notification if data is available. I cannot use Google Cloud Messaging or Firebase Cloud Messaging as I am porting an Android app which doesn't use cloud messaging services.

Is there any way to implement this in swift?

Comment: Improved language, removed acronyms which wouldn't be recognized by an iOS audience.

This question needs some more context to be answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you have in mind for "periodically".

You could set up [Background fetch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56). In that situation, iOS will wake up your app to let it download things.

You can then use the local notifications whenever you detect new data.

The issue here is that you have no control over how often your app gets called. You can provide a hint, but iOS can decide not to wake your app for a while if it thinks it's appropriate. Don't count on being called more often than once an hour.

Another option is to have the app woken up by sending it a silent notification whenever there's something new (or at regular intervals).

The best option would still be to send notifications (silent or not) whenever there's actually something to send.